# smooth div scroll with divs wrapping

Tags: jquery, css, html, smooth-scrolling

So...I am using the Smooth Div Scroll plugin found here...
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

it's simple implementation...So i'm using the touch example
Only difference is...I am using Divs instead of images...to scroll through.

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
  <div class='item'>One</div>
  <div class='item'>Two</div>
  <div class='item'>Three</div>
  <div class='item'>Four</div>
  <div class='item'>Five</div>
  <div class='item'>Six</div>
  <div class='item'>Seven</div>
  <div class='item'>Eight</div>
  <div class='item'>Nine</div>
  <div class='item'>Ten</div>
</div>
```

My js is here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    hotSpotScrolling : false,
    touchScrolling : true,
    manualContinuousScrolling : false,
    mousewheelScrolling : false
});
```

CSS

```
.item {
  height: 35px;
  width: 245px;
}

#makeMeScrollable {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 43% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: black solid 1px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is, that when I do that...I the first nine divs...one after another...up to about 6 and I can click and scroll to see the rest. Up to 9...the problem is that Div 10 
is for some reason wrapping around and is underneath Div 1.

The reason for this I believe is because the scollableArea wrapper div that is put around 
my 10 divs by calling the scrollable function is a few pixels too short. It is set to auto so it's supposed to (i assume) automatically set itself to be big enough...

I suppose I can hack it and dynamically extend it a few pixels and it'll be fine...Because I tried increasing its pixels in the chrome developer...

So yeah...Id post a screenshot...but I can't...because I'm new lol

Comment: Where is `div.scrollableArea`?

Comment: the div.scrollableArea is a wrapper div that The plugin puts around my 10 divs.

Answer (score 0):

Does anything happen if you remove the border from the CSS?

```
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Is it possible to give the div's a fixed width? Something like:

```
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: black solid 1px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```